# $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}$ converges implies $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^{2}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove (although it might not even true!) that:

$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}$ converges implies $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^{2}$ converges

It seems true, but I can find a straight forward proof.

Comment: You want to beware of cancellation in the first series that goes away after squaring terms.  For instance, does $x_k = (-1)^k \sqrt{k}$ satisfy the formula?

Comment: Yes, the limit of the arithmetic mean and $x_{k}$ is the same since $x_{k}$ convergent. So the first sequence converges, and also the second one, since the second sum is approx $\frac {H_{n}}{n}\approx \frac {logn}{n}$

Comment: Note that this is true if you add some extra hypothesis on the $x_k$. For instance $\forall k, 0\leq x_k\leq 1$ (epsilon-delta proof) or $x_k$ converges (Cesaro theorem).

Answer (score 4):

$x_{m^2}=2m-1,x_n=0$ if $n\neq m^2$
The average approaches 1, but the mean-square grows like $\sqrt{n}$.
If $m^2\leq n<(m+1)^2$, then the sum 1+0+0+3+0+0+0+0+5+... equals $m^2$, so the mean is $m^2/n$ which is between $m^2/(m+1)^2$ and $1$.
The sum-square is $\sum_{k=1}^m (2k-1)^2$ which equals $m(4m^2-1)/3$, so the mean-square is $(4m^3-m)/3n$, which is near $4m/3$, or $4\sqrt{n}/3$.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Still don't understand. sorry.

Comment: Here is a related question, but with the restriction that the sequence is positive and *bounded:* https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4151934/42969