# Convergence of arithmetic mean of bounded and positive sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $(a_i)$ and $(b_i)$ are two seuqence of real numbers with $0<a_i \leq A$ and $0<b_i \leq B$, where $A,B \in \mathbb R$. If
$$
m^{-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} a_i b_i \rightarrow P, ~\text{as} ~m \rightarrow \infty,
$$
for some $P \in \mathbb R$.
Does $m^{-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} a_i^2 b_i^2 \rightarrow Q$, as $m \rightarrow \infty$ always hold for some $Q \in \mathbb R$? More generally, does $m^{-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} a_i^p b_i^q \rightarrow Q$, as $m \rightarrow \infty$ always hold for some $Q \in \mathbb R$ for all $p,q \in \mathbb R_+$?

The general $p,q$ statement is false. The counterexample is given by user10354138 in the comments. For the case of $p=q=2$, my idea is to define $c_i:=a_i b_i$ and show that the sequence $(c_i)$ is a random sequence with respect to some probability distribution. Hence $m^{-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} c_i^2$ converges. Is my idea correct? Can anyone give a rigorous proof or a counterexample? Thanks~

Comment: The general $p,q$ statement is false, because you can impose $a_nb_n=1$ and let $(b_n)$ be any sequence of $\frac12,2$ (in particular, a sequence for which $m^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^m b_n$ does not converge).

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks, it is a good counterexample.

Comment: Here is a counterexample: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2651842/42969

Comment: @Martin R Thanks. The counterexample in the link you provided exactly solves my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't have to converge.
It is clear that the sequence is bounded by $\max c_i \times \lim m^{-1} \sum c_i$, so the convergence boils down to considering if the sequence could bounce back and forth.
As it turns out, it could, and we show this by creating a counter example.

We create the sequence $ c_i$ by concatenating copies of $(1, 1)$ and $(2, 0)$.  [For simplicity. If you want positive terms, use $(1.99, 0.01)$ instead.]
Notice that if we concatenate  with any combinations of $ (1,1)$ or $(2,0)$, we will always get $m^{-1} \sum c_i \rightarrow 1$. So   the conditions of the problem are satisfied.
By concatenating enough copies of $(1,1)$, we could make $ m^{-1} \sum c_i^2 \rightarrow 1 $, and by concatenating enough copies of $(2, 0)$, we could make $ m^{-1} \sum c_i^2 \rightarrow 2 $.
Thus, the limit need not exist.